# mysql fetch value (end of value=0)

Tags: php, mysql

In database I have a table that looks like

```
a  | B     |id |
----------------
10 | 20~30 |1 |
20 | 10~0  |2 |
30 | 10~0  |3 |
```

and I want to retrieve rows where second half of `B` (after `~`) does not end in `0`.  So in the above example, I'd want to match the first row, but not the other two.  How can I do that?

I am using `mysql_fetch_object`.

Comment: Did not understand... what is your expected result from the given data ?

Comment: why you tagged java without any code?

Comment: i need only id=1 dont need 2 and 3 because b field value ends with zero

Comment: yea that's easy. As I said.. Show us what you already have.

Comment: i already tell that my database in the question

Comment: `select * from table where substring_index(B,'~',-1)+0 >0`

Comment: you can use regex pattern in select query :
 "select * from table where B NOT LIKE '%~0%'"

Comment: I cant get proper sql

Comment: Thank you Abhik Chakraborty your query working well and suitable for my logic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE B NOT LIKE '%~0';
```

Comment: you can select all values from table its not ending with '~0'